# What listener would tell me that when the drawing of a view has finished so i can get height of the view?

Tags: android, view, listener

I am programmatically adding a view to the Layout and after i add that i need to get the height of new view when i ask for height of new view simply i get 0. Is there any way to know when a view has finished drawing and it can provide its height ?

To be more clear i am adding a AdVhirlLayout to the my root layout with `myMainLayout.addView(adWhirlLayout, 0, adLayoutparams);` the next line is `adWhirlLayout.getHeight();`
 which retruns 0. I have added `OnHierarchyChangeListener`to the adWhirlLayout and i am trying to get the height of the adWhirlLayout but still it returns 0. There must be another listener which will let me know if the drawing of adWhirlLayout has finished.

```
adWhirlLayout.setOnHierarchyChangeListener(new OnHierarchyChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onChildViewRemoved(View parent, View child) {}

    @Override
    public void onChildViewAdded(View parent, View child) {
        adWhirlLayout.getHeight();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add an [`OnLayoutChangeListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLayoutChangeListener.html).

You can also override onSizeChanged in the view to respond when the view size is set on layout.

Comment: Thanks for answer. OnLayoutChangeListener's api level is 11 and my target api level is 7.

Comment: I ended up doing same thing on myself too.